# Excel - Combo Box всплывающая подсказка

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Возможно ли реализовать показ всплывающей подсказки при наведении на вариант из раскрытого ComboBox (не ActiveX)?

В общем, нужно кроссплатформенное решение: отображение определенного описания в качестве комментария, либо в определенной ячейке при наведении на вариант в выпадающем списке.

Я видел реализации, но они используют либо ActiveX, либо UserForms, либо Windows API. Неужели нет никакого костыля?

Как вариант, подошла бы и обычная ячейка с проверкой данных

Answer (score 1):

Как сами заметили, нужен *костыль*, т.к. в *Excel* нет встроенных инструментов, которые могли бы помочь реализовать задумку.

Макросом. Но пока не выбрали значение из списка - нет события, по которому можно разрешить работу кода.

Похоже, с ограничениями, которые указал автор, никак.